# MSChart pie diagram overlapping labels issue

Tags: c#

after searching for a proper solution for the given problem, I could not accept the solutions in the forum and also the solutions provided by Microsoft are not what I was looking for.

Here is an example of the problem:

[(Link to image) MSChart pie diagram with overlapping labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHDYl.png)

I tried to set the labels outside of the diagram, but first, the connection lines are kind of ugly and second, the outside labels use too much space.
Also the SmartLabels didn't solve the problem.

Edit:
Does anybody know how to set the labels radius? It seems like the center of each label is a fixed radius?!

Did anybody figure out how to fix the overlapping labels?

Comment: You shouldn't answer your own question within the question. You are encouraged however to phrase your question as such (a question), and write your own answer to it.

Comment: @wilbur Sorry, didn't know about it. Hope it's ok now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your data!

You have to set points in the Series, so it is easy to create a list at first, enter your data to that list, sort the list in descending or ascending order of the value you want to display and than resort that list to place the smallest value between the two biggest value.

For example:

100
70
50
30
10
5
(old order)

100
5
70
10
50
30
(new order)

Resulting diagram:

[(Link to image) MSChart pie diagram without overlapping labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIEU2.png)

Lets call every slice of the pie a category, with a value and a tooltip text. 
So you need a class like this:

```
private class CatValue
{
    public string CategoryName;
    public decimal Value;
    public string TooltipText;
}
```

Now put your data in the List object, for example like this:

```
List<CatValue> listOfPieSlices = new List<CatValue>();
// ....
// Add your data to the list object
// ....
// Sort the list in ascending order
listOfPieSlices.Sort((x, y) => x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value));
// Sort the list in descending order
// listOfPieSlices.Sort((x, y) => -x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value));
//
// Now sort the "listOfPieSlices" with the specialSort methode:
listOfPieSlices = specialSort<CatValue>(listOfPieSlices);

// Now create the Series of DataPoints
Series sortedPoints = new Series("PCDSsorted");
for (int i = 0; i < listOfPieSlices.Count; i++)
{
    sortedPoints.Points.AddY(Math.Abs(listOfPieSlices[i].Value));        
    sortedPoints.Points[i].Label = listOfPieSlices[i].CategoryName + ":  "+listOfPieSlices[i].Value.ToString();
    sortedPoints.Points[i].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);
    sortedPoints.Points[i].LabelToolTip = listOfPieSlices[i].Tooltip;
    sortedPoints.Points[i].ToolTip = listOfPieSlices[i].Tooltip;
}    

private List<T> specialSort<T>(List<T> objects)
{
    if (objects == null) return null;

    int count = objects.Count;
    List<T> sortedList = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i += 2)
    {
        if(i == count - 1)
            sortedList.Add(objects[i / 2]);
        else
        {
            sortedList.Add(objects[i / 2]);
            sortedList.Add(objects[count - 1 - (i / 2)]);
        }
    }
    return sortedList;
}
```

Hope this works for someone out there as well as it did for me.

Happy coding